# What does each graph quadrant mean with LDAvis plot in R?

Tags: pca, data-visualization, latent-dirichlet-alloc, interactive-visualization

I write about [the graph explained in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IksL96ls4o0) that shows a big probability mass. It's a web-based interactive visualization of topics estimated using
Latent Dirichlet Allocation that is built using a combination of R and D3; the default for scaling the set of
inter-topic distances defaults to Principal Components, but other algorithms are also enabled. [image: LDAvis]

This is the way that it finally shows with some data I found online and used to understand Latent Dirichlet Allocation topic modeling. As far as I understand, this graph is ideal to give out final names to each topic according to the frequency or relevance of each term given the topic but I've got two questions:

**1. What would you simply say about topic 8 position on the graph?** Meaning that I can't tell what each square represents in this graph, I can't tell in plain words what's the difference between topic 1 and 10, or topic 8 and 3, given their position on this graph?

**2. What can you say about the big gray line in comparison with the red filling when lambda is 0?** I think I get that when lambda is 1, it's meaning about plain frequency of the term in the whole corpus vs the frequency of the terms in that topic, but I'm not sure I get it with putting more weight in the ratio from red to gray: what is the gray line saying about that term and how is red contrasting?

You can get this for a model named `lda_model$plot()` found [here](http://text2vec.org/topic_modeling.html).

I am looking for the main idea at least. If there is info I need to add please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LDA Vis algorithm uses a Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to reduce N-dimensional vectors to 2D vectors and get these (x,y) coordinates. In short PCA will breakdown N variables to n < N which will describe best your original data set. It's not inherent to the LDA model, it is just a way to plot the topics and the distance among them.